# How to use a logical operator in a column expression

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to create an SQL statement that has a column that is true if any of several logical conditions based on the row are true.

I tried using the [OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) but I am getting an error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

In actuality the logic is complicated, but I have reduced it to the smallest test case that reproduces the issue:

```
SELECT 1 or 0 AS result;
```

Or without naming the column:

```
SELECT 1 OR 0;
```

In this example, I'm expecting one row with a value of 1 (true). I tried with various arrangements of parentheses but none of them worked, most with the same error.

How do I perform a logical operation in a column expression?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [bitwise or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT 1 | 0 AS result;
```

Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a case scenario (or IF statements):

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN column = condition1
            OR column in ('condition2','condition3')
            OR column like '%condition4%'
        THEN some_result
        WHEN column = condition1
             AND column = condition2
        THEN some_other_result
        ELSE catch_all_result
    END
```

If you add multiple `when`, only the first one that meets the criteria (in order) will be returned.

[CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I'm actually already using CASE statements for each of my conditions and was just trying to OR them together, but it looks like this route requires another CASE to nest all of them...

Comment: Nesting is one way... Creating more columns  (for each of your nested results) could be another way, then use those columns in your new case statement. This could be helpful for debugging and readability (depending on your complexity, maybe even performance), but otherwise nesting works too.

Comment: One other way (if you have really complex conditions, but relatively small dataset) would be to create an update statement for each (in the same order you would have used in the case statement), and update all rows where your column is not yet populated with the value you want. Gives a bit more control over documenting why, and separates some of the complexity.